# How to use external python modules such as the module 'requests' when running executable python scripts such as .command files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, command, executable

I made a python script into an executable file by turning it into a .command file and adding the #!/usr/bin/env python3 on the first line of the file.

When I double click to run the file, the file does run on the terminal, however the installed modules do not seem to be linked to the file.

import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'

Is there a way to use external module such as the 'requests' module when running an executable form of a python script?

Answer (score 0):

By "." you mean "./"?

How to you normaly run it?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Linux, but probably works on Mac as well:
First locate where python3 is:

```sh
which python3
```

For me that's `/usr/bin/python3`.
Then add it in the first line of the script:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/python3
import requests
print("something")
```

Add execute permissions to the file:

```sh
chmod +x file.command
```

Execute the file:

```
./file.command
```

If you're still getting a `ModuleNotFoundError`, make sure the library is installed for the current version of python with `pip3 install requests`